# No wlan interface on a Yocto build for Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, yocto

I'm using Yocto (Kirkstone branch) to build a distro to be used on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

When loaded and running, the wireless adapter is not recognized by the OS. `ifconfig` shows only the `lo` device - no `wlan` at all.

Yocto's config:

**`conf/bblayers.conf`**

```
# POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION is increased each time build/conf/bblayers.conf
# changes incompatibly
POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/poky/meta \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/poky/meta-poky \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  /home/quadfloor/release_1/src/meta-raspberrypi \
  "
```

**`conf/local.conf`**

```
MACHINE = "raspberrypi0-wifi"
SERIAL_CONSOLE = ""
DISABLE_RPI_BOOT_LOGO = "1"
DISABLE_OVERSCAN = "1"
DISABLE_SPLASH = "1"
BOOT_DELAY = "0"
GPU_MEM_256 = "128"
GPU_MEM_512 = "196"
GPU_MEM_1024 = "396"
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"
DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " wifi "
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " linux-firmware-bcm43430 wpa-supplicant"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.bz2 ext4 rpi-sdimg"
SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE = "ext4"
```

I've tested the hardware by installing RapiOS and the wireless interface is usabe and working fine.

There are no errors showing on boot (`dmesg`) and wpa_supplicant is installed, but cannot work due to inexistance of `wlan` interface.

Stuck for some days in that... help appreciated.

Comment: none of the tutorials I've found include `DISTRO_FEATURES:append` or `IMAGE_INSTALL:append` entries in `local.conf` - having said that, is wifi being disabled in `/boot/config.txt` perhaps?

Comment: I don't know why people continue to use the deprecated ifconfig - which wouldn't show interfaces. `ls /sys/class/net` will show which network devices are detected